# Working with Jersey client in rx style

Tags: java, jersey, java-8, nio, reactive-programming

Agenda: I want to get http-responses `asynchronously` but then work with them in synchronous way.
I use `Jersey` client and `jersey-rx-client-java8`.
It's my code:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
RxClient<RxCompletionStageInvoker> client = Rx.newClient(RxCompletionStageInvoker.class, executorService);

Stream<String> urls_stream = Stream.of("stackoverflow.com", "stackoverflow.com");
urls_stream.map(url -> {
    return client
            .target(url)
            .request()
            .rx()
            .get()
            .whenComplete((response, throwable) -> {
                // this should be executed by 1 thread
                out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
                if (null != throwable) throwable.printStackTrace();
            })
            .toCompletableFuture();
})
// Wait completion
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(list -> {
    CompletableFuture.allOf(list).join();
});
```

I have another code, this example works faster then the first.

```
String[] url_str = { ... };
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(urls.length);
for (String url_str : urls) {
    Future<Response> response = client.target(url_str).request().async().get(new InvocationCallback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void completed(Response response) {
            out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
            cdl.countDown();
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            cdl.countDown();
        }
    });
}
cdl.await();
```

I want to archive that the first example works faster (but I don't want to increase threads in pool).

Comment: it is not clear what you want to achieve, please explain more what you expect and what makes you believe that your requests work synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, Jersey use one thread per connection even in async mode. Only one possible solution is increase threads in pool.